# Why count no relationships takes long

Tags: neo4j, relationship

Why following query takes so long:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ start r=relationship(*) return count(r);                                                                              
+----------+
| count(r) |
+----------+
| 0        |
+----------+
1 row
217819 ms
```

- DB: 25M nodes, 0 relationships
- Machine: 2xCPU , 8GB RAM

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: Did you have a lot of rels before? Then it might scan the still large rel-record file for existing relationships.